# Why is my network unreachable during boot?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, mount

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, which includes the changeover from Upstart to `systemd`.  Since then, when the system boots, about half the time it drops into an emergency shell.

I've tracked this down to the system's attempt to mount a directory from a remote data server.  From `journalctl` during a failed boot attempt:

```
$ journalctl -b 0 -u dataserver.mount -u network-online.target -u network.target -u network-pre.target -u remote-fs.target -u remote-fs-pre.target --no-page 
systemd[1]: Reached target Network (Pre).
systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
systemd[1]: Mounting /dataserver...
mount[293]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
systemd[1]: dataserver.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
systemd[1]: Failed to mount /dataserver.
systemd[1]: dataserver.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

`dataserver.mount` is the mount to the remote directory.  It appears that the network is unavailable when `systemd` attempts to mount the `dataserver` directory, which causes the crash to the emergency shell.

I've tried to sort out what's going on for three days now, but I'm at a loss.

A few notes:

- `dataserver.mount` is auto-generated from the `/etc/fstab` entry that carried over from Ubuntu 14.04.

Here's the `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
# Mount dataserver-store to /dataserver
99.99.99.99:/data/NFS/datastore01            /dataserver          nfs     nofail,rw,soft,intr,actimeo=60 0 0
```

Here's the generated `systemd` unit `/run/systemd/generator/dataserver.mount`:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

[Mount]
What=99.99.99.99:/data/NFS/datastore01
Where=/dataserver
Type=nfs
Options=nofail,rw,soft,intr,actimeo=60
```

- I'm not using the `_netdev` option in the `dataserver` entry of `/etc/fstab` because my understanding is that it's redundant `systemd`, which automatically recognizes network devices for NFS mounts.
- I have tons of output from various diagnostic efforts, too much to post without knowing what's relevant.  I'm happy to add anything on request.

How do I determine why the network is unreachable at the time the mount is attempted during boot?

**Edit**: I spent all day yesterday trying to figure out how my network is configured.  I'm still not certain, but here's what I can tell you:  `NetworkManager.service`, `systemd-networkd.service`, and `ifupdown.service` are inactive/dead on the system.  `networking.service` is active on the system.  `/etc/network/interfaces` exists on the system, but I have no way of knowing what program or service is doing what with it.

Comment: How is your network configured (e.g., is it through `/etc/network/interfaces`, or something else?)

Comment: @derobert I believe it's `/etc/network/interfaces` and the `systemd` `networking` service.